# Sort php array inside loop by number

Tags: php, arrays, loops

```
<?php
foreach ($jsonObj as $items) {
 foreach ($items["items"] as $itemlist){ 
// $itemlist['position']; I want them to echo in that order
echo $itemlist['name'];
}
}
?>
```

I have an array that I loop through. In that array there is name and order. I would like to display them in numerical order, how can I make it print out the itemlist with lowest number first, then the second etc?

Comment: try this before second foreach loop sort($items["items"]);

Comment: I understand I have to use some kind of sort. asort for an example. What I don't understand is that I don't have the array to sort before I already print it.

Comment: I'm not quite sure i follow.
If you don't have the array, how do you print it in the first place?

Comment: I do have an array, but I need to loop it first to get the $itemlist['position']... but then I have them printed out already

Comment: That wasn't very clear from your original question.
If you can clear that up by editing your question, i'll change the DV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `usort` with `cmp_function` for this. Try this function:

```
function compare_position($a, $b) {
    return $a['position'] - $b['position'];
}
```

Then when you are iterating through the array:

```
foreach ($jsonObj as $items) {
  usort($items['items'], "compare_position");
  foreach ($items["items"] as $itemlist){ 
       echo $itemlist['position']; 
       echo $itemlist['name'];
  }
}
```

More about `usort` can be found here http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you, you're a good person.. I understand it now. Some evil people wrote bad comments about me(deleted now)... you made it very clear to me. Not just code but I understand what I didn't understand before.

Comment: @BadrHari you should look at my answer - it provides a more flexible solution as well as being clearer for other programmers what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You need to prepare an array of the positions to sort on first. Sort then sorts by reference allowing you to loop through it a second time but this time as sorted by `array_multisort()`.

```
<?php
foreach($jsonObj as $items) {
    foreach($items['items'] as $key => $itemlist) {
        $positions[$key] = $itemlist['position'];
        $names[$key] = $itemlist['name'];
    }
    array_multisort($positions, SORT_ASC, $items['items']);
    foreach($items['items'] as $itemlist) {
        echo $itemlist['name'], "<br />";
        // Now in asc order of positions
    }
}
```

The advantage of this is if other attributes come along that you want to sort on you can do that. For example if there's a chance 'position' will be the same for two people, you could then sort alphabetically by their name etc..

Full solution on Codepad, two answers compared:
http://codepad.viper-7.com/5yJ72S